# Internet usage monitor software

Tags: internet, internet-connection, broadband

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software to report internet traffic for home user](https://superuser.com/questions/107879/software-to-report-internet-traffic-for-home-user)

My mobile Internet connection has a daily usage limit, so I'm looking for some software which can monitor both the upload and download usage for the current session.

I'm using Windows xp.

Can anyone suggest any good freeware for this purpose?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: @raki Care to explain how your question is any different from the one linked by @Mehper?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Track4Win](http://www.track4win.com/Monitor_Internet_Usage.asp).

> Track4Win software enables you to monitor Internet use and web site
>   surfing on networked computers. Tracking employee computer usage
>   including Internet tracking is necessary for your business today. You
>   must choose a good internet usage monitor software product and install
>   it in your computer network to monitor Internet usage and computer
>   activities. Track4Win is a superb product to monitor Internet usage!
>   Track4win is an inexpensive tool to monitor web usage and computer
>   activities.

[image]

Comment: But this is not a freware :( and i just need to know the data usage count for my machine only

Answer (score 0):

Some ISPs provide browser plugins that display bandwidth usage and have web API's so you can create your own monitoring apps.

For example [Zen](http://www.zen.co.uk/business/broadband/business-broadband/broadband-usage-checkers.aspx)